# Modal popup close button is not working in MVC project

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal

I want to use modal popup where my close button is not working. These are the following concerns.

I want to use  `<button type="submit" id="submit">Produce</button>` inside the `@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))` to save the data and also want to populate modal popup upon this `Produce` button click.

As I am able to get the modal popup but I `am not able to close the modal`. If I change the `button type` to `button` then `close` button works.  But I want 
 type to `Submit`.

I tried the following code to do but no luck so far. I am struggling since 2 days. Anyone have any ideas then please share. Thank you.

```
//My form

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {   
       @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.txtName)
       <button type="submit" id="submit">Produce Page</button>      
    } 



 //My Modal

    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModal" aria-hidden="true">
        ...
                <div class="modal-header">
                    ...
<button type="button" class="close" onclick="CloseModalPopup();" aria-label="Close">
   <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
     </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                        ...
                    </div>

 <div class="modal-footer">
<button type="button" onclick="CloseModalPopup();">Close</button>
<button type="button"><a href="~/MyHome/MyHome">Go to My Home</a></button>
        </div>
  </div>
```

My JavaScript code:

```
  $(function () {
        $('#submit').click(function () {
              var value = $('#txtName').val();
               if (value) {
                   $("#myModal").modal('show');              
                }          
        });
});


 function CloseModalPopup() {       
            $("#myModal").modal('hide');
    }

    });
```

Please help me. I am struggling to find the solutions.

Comment: Why not just use the attribute, data-dismiss="modal" on your close buttons?

Comment: @npearson, I tried that as well but still not working.

Comment: Your submit button is posting the form so you lose all state on your page. Why are you showing a modal when posting the form?

Comment: @npearson, I want to show modal because I want to display message as well as `<button type="button"><a href="~/MyHome/MyHome">Go to My Home</a></button>`  and `<button type="button" onclick="CloseModalPopup();">Close</button>` button so that User can go to different page

Comment: @npearson, if there is any other way to do the same then I am very much happy to know that.

Comment: You are defining CloseModalPopup inside a function so it is unreachable from the global scope.

Comment: @Izabela, I changed that but still no luck.

Comment: @Raj Do you have two Index actions on your HomeController, one marked [HttpGet] and one [HttpPost], or just the single action?

Comment: @npearson, Yes, I have 2 Actions, one for [HttpGet] and [HttpPost]

Comment: What does the HttpPost action return? The same view as the get?

Comment: @npearson, It saves all the data into database.

Comment: @npearson, how to post the form asynchronously. Can you please provide me some sample code for this. I will follow that.

Comment: There are many many online examples on how to post a form asynchronously. Please try one and post back with any specific issue.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, I found the solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

use data-dismiss attribute

```html
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

use data-bs-dismiss="modal"

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
```

Comment: Hello, please don't post code only and add an explantation as to why you think that this is the optimal solution. People are supposed to learn from your answer, which might not occur if they just copy paste code without knowing why it should be used.